# How to show reactive matrix values in R studio console while running Shiny script?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am working on a solution to my post yesterday, [in R Shiny, how to move a linked object into modal dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143167/in-r-shiny-how-to-move-a-linked-object-into-modal-dialog). Help with the following question will help me with a possible solution to yesterday's post.

The below code works as intended. Matrix 1 values downstream to "Scenario 1" of matrix 2, and matrix 2 allows input of additional scenarios with all scenarios plotted as separate lines. However, I'm trying to output the values of matrix 1 and matrix 2, on a real-time "reactive" basis, to the R studio console so I can see what's going on with the matrix values as the code runs. In the below code I tried this with matrix 2 (`tmpMat2`) but was unsuccessful: so I commented those lines out in the below code so that it runs and someone can help back me out of the corner I find myself in. Clearly, those commented-out lines are wrong.

Please, how do I show matrix 1 (`tmpMat1`) and matrix 2 (`tmpMat2`) values real-time in R studio console as the user inputs into the matrices?

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumMat <- function(x){return(rep(sum(x,na.rm = TRUE), 10))}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      matrixInput("matrix1",
                  label ="Matrix 1 (scenario 1):",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5), nrow = 1, ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric"),
      matrixInput("matrix2",
                  label = "Matrix 2:",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, rep("Scenario 1", 2))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                  cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric")
      ),
      mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  # rv <- reactiveValues(tmpMat=NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    a <- apply(input$matrix2,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    b <- apply(input$matrix1,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    c <- if(length(a) == 2){c(b)} else {c(b,a[,-1:-2])}
    d <- ncol(input$matrix2)
    tmpMat2 <- matrix(c(c), ncol = d)
    colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))

    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")){
      tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
      rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
      }
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    input$matrix2
    # rv$tmpMat <- tmpMat2
  })
  # observe({print(rv$tmpMat)})
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix2)/2), 
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario= colnames(input$matrix2)[i*2-1],X=seq_len(10),
                 Y=sumMat(input$matrix2[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I added the following bits of code in the `server` section, where additions are flagged with "# Added" at the end of each line. These code additions, when running the App, show how the reactive objects are evolving in the RStudio console as the user inputs. Though the output view isn't very clean. Would be good if I could insert some sort of break or text flag when moving from one `observe()` to the next.

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(tmpMat1=NULL,tmpMat2obsMat1=NULL,tmpMat2obsMat2=NULL) # Added
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    a <- apply(input$matrix2,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    b <- apply(input$matrix1,2,'length<-',max(nrow(input$matrix2),nrow(input$matrix1)))
    c <- if(length(a) == 2){c(b)} else {c(b,a[,-1:-2])}
    d <- ncol(input$matrix2)
    tmpMat2 <- matrix(c(c), ncol = d)
    colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))

    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")){
      tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
      rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
      }
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
    
    rv$tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1 # Added
    rv$tmpMat2obsMat1 <- input$matrix2 # Added
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    if(any(colnames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix2) == "")){
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
      }
    input$matrix2
    rv$tmpMat2obsMat2 <- input$matrix2 # Added 
  })
  
  observe({print(rv$tmpMat1)}) # Added
  observe({print(rv$tmpMat2obsMat1)}) # Added
  observe({print(rv$tmpMat2obsMat2)}) # Added
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix2)/2), 
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario= colnames(input$matrix2)[i*2-1],X=seq_len(10),
                 Y=sumMat(input$matrix2[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    req(plotData())
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the lines marked with "# Added" in the second set of code added to the above revised post. I also added the following lines to the server section, at the bottom (not shown above), in order generate global variables for each reactive object so I can review ending values after running the code (helps with debugging):

```
oe1 <- reactive({
    rv$tmpMat1})
  observeEvent(oe1(),{tmpMat1.R <<- oe1()})
  
  oe2 <- reactive({
    rv$tmpMat2obsMat1})
  observeEvent(oe2(),{tmpMat2obsMat1.R <<- oe2()})
  
  oe3 <- reactive({
    rv$tmpMat2obsMat2})
  observeEvent(oe3(),{tmpMat2obsMat2.R <<- oe3()})
```