# How to modify reactivity chain so last object modified controls other chained objects?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

**[New note 1: final resolved code posted at the very bottom reflecting ismirsehregal's solution of 03-Dec-2021, and some minor tweaks marked "# ADDED" and "# MODIFIED". ADD is for addressing the bug I encountered when deleting rows from matrix 1 after matrix 2 had had values added (as commented below), and "MODIFIED" is to conform column headers for matrices 1 and 2 (there was no point in them having different column headers).**

When running the below code, I'd like the last object modified in the reactivity chain to "control" or "dominate" other objects in that reactivity chain. In this code, the chained reactive objects are "matrix1" and "matrix2". Inputs into matrix1 downstream to matrix2, and inputs into the first 2 columns of matrix2 upstream to matrix1. As drafted, inputs into matrix2 trump inputs into matrix1. I'd like whichever matrix was last input into to trump the other matrix. Can someone help me with this?

The images at the bottom help illustrate.

I have messed with `isolate()` and other things to try getting this to work the way I want. I've also had the problem of the matrices getting caught in a loop where values bounce back and forth between the 2 matrices. I don't have a complete grasp of `isolate()` yet.

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumMat <- function(x){return(rep(sum(x,na.rm = TRUE), 10))}

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      matrixInput("matrix1",
                  label ="Matrix 1 (scenario 1):",
                  value = matrix(c(60,5),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("X","Y"))),
                  rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                  class = "numeric"),
      actionButton(inputId = "showMat2", "Add scenarios"),br(),br(),
    ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")){rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))    }
    isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showMat2,{
    showModal(
      modalDialog(
        matrixInput("matrix2",
                    label = "Matrix 2:",
                    value = input$matrix1,
                    rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
                    cols = list(extend = TRUE, delta = 2, delete = TRUE, multiheader = TRUE),
                    class = "numeric"),
        footer = tagList(modalButton("Close"))
      ))
    observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
      tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
      rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
      colnames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Scenario",rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each=2,length.out=ncol(tmpMat2)))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2))
      isolate(updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat2[,1:2]))
    })
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix1)/2), 
             function(i){
               tibble(
                 Scenario= colnames(input$matrix1)[i*2-1],X=seq_len(10),
                 Y=sumMat(input$matrix1[,(i*2-1):(i*2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e) NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotData() %>% ggplot() + 
      geom_line(aes(x = X, y = Y, colour = as.factor(Scenario))) +
      theme(legend.title=element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

New note 1: final resolved code below

```
sumMat <- function(x) {return(rep(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), 10))}

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    matrixInput(
      "matrix1",
      label = "Matrix 1:", # MODIFIED HEADER
      value = matrix(c(60,5),ncol=2,dimnames=list(NULL,rep("Scenario 1",2))), # MODIFIED HEADER
      rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
      cols = list(multiheader = TRUE), # ADD
      class = "numeric"
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = "showMat2", "Add scenarios"),br(),br(),
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  currentMat <- reactiveVal(isolate(input$matrix1))
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
    if(any(rownames(input$matrix1)=="")){rownames(tmpMat1)<-paste("Row",seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))}
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
    
    tmpMat2 <- currentMat()
    
    if(nrow(tmpMat1) > nrow(tmpMat2)){tmpMat2 <- rbind(tmpMat2, rep(NA, ncol(tmpMat2)))}
  
    # ADDED
    if(nrow(tmpMat2) > nrow(tmpMat1)){tmpMat1 <- rbind(tmpMat1, rep(NA, ncol(tmpMat1)))}
  
    currentMat(cbind(tmpMat1[drop=FALSE], tmpMat2[,-1:-2,drop=FALSE]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showMat2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      matrixInput(
        "matrix2",
        label = "Matrix 2:",
        value = currentMat(),
        rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
        cols = list(extend = TRUE,delta = 2,delete = TRUE,multiheader = TRUE),
        class = "numeric"
      ),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Close"))
    ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
    rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
    colnames(tmpMat2) <-
      paste("Scenario", rep(1:ncol(tmpMat2),each = 2,length.out = ncol(tmpMat2)))
    currentMat(tmpMat2)
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat2[, 1:2, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix1) / 2),
             function(i) {
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix1)[i * 2 - 1],
                 X = seq_len(10),
                 Y = sumMat(input$matrix1[, (i * 2 - 1):(i * 2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e)
      NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotData() %>% ggplot() +
      geom_line(aes(
        x = X,
        y = Y,
        colour = as.factor(Scenario)
      )) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work:

- remember to use `drop = FALSE`
- never nest observers

---

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

sumMat <- function(x) {
  return(rep(sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), 10))
}

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    matrixInput(
      "matrix1",
      label = "Matrix 1 (scenario 1):",
      value = matrix(c(60, 5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y"))),
      rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
      class = "numeric"
    ),
    actionButton(inputId = "showMat2", "Add scenarios"),
    br(),
    br(),
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  currentMat <- reactiveVal(isolate(input$matrix1))
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix1, {
    tmpMat1 <- input$matrix1
    if (any(rownames(input$matrix1) == "")) {
      rownames(tmpMat1) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix1)))
    }
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat1)
    
    tmpMat2 <- currentMat()
    if(nrow(tmpMat1) > nrow(tmpMat2)){
      tmpMat2 <- rbind(tmpMat2, rep(NA, ncol(tmpMat2)))
    }
    if(nrow(tmpMat2) > nrow(tmpMat1)){
      tmpMat1 <- rbind(tmpMat1, rep(NA, ncol(tmpMat1)))
    }
    currentMat(cbind(tmpMat1, tmpMat2[,-1:-2]))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$showMat2, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      matrixInput(
        "matrix2",
        label = "Matrix 2:",
        value = currentMat(),
        rows = list(extend = TRUE, delete = TRUE),
        cols = list(
          extend = TRUE,
          delta = 2,
          delete = TRUE,
          multiheader = TRUE
        ),
        class = "numeric"
      ),
      footer = tagList(modalButton("Close"))
    ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$matrix2, {
    tmpMat2 <- input$matrix2
    rownames(tmpMat2) <- paste("Row", seq_len(nrow(input$matrix2)))
    colnames(tmpMat2) <-
      paste("Scenario", rep(
        1:ncol(tmpMat2),
        each = 2,
        length.out = ncol(tmpMat2)
      ))
    currentMat(tmpMat2)
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix2", value = tmpMat2)
    updateMatrixInput(session, inputId = "matrix1", value = tmpMat2[, 1:2, drop = FALSE])
  })
  
  plotData <- reactive({
    tryCatch(
      lapply(seq_len(ncol(input$matrix1) / 2),
             function(i) {
               tibble(
                 Scenario = colnames(input$matrix1)[i * 2 - 1],
                 X = seq_len(10),
                 Y = sumMat(input$matrix1[, (i * 2 - 1):(i * 2), drop = FALSE])
               )
             }) %>% bind_rows(),
      error = function(e)
        NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    plotData() %>% ggplot() +
      geom_line(aes(
        x = X,
        y = Y,
        colour = as.factor(Scenario)
      )) +
      theme(legend.title = element_blank())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Works very well! One thing I noticed is in my original code, any additional scenario inputs into matrix 2 are retained and retrieved when the user clicks on the action button again, as it should. With your changes, this >1 scenario retention no longer works. All >1 scenario inputs are lost.

Comment: Please check my edit. Your above code didn't retain the values correctly.

Comment: Hi, additional scenarios beyond "Scenario 1" are now retained in your revised code. However, the last object to be input into no longer dominates. For example, when I input values into matrix 1 and then click on the action button to add more scenarios, the matrix 1 inputs do not appear in "Scenario 1" of matrix 2 like they should. Inputs into matrix 2, however, do correctly render reactively in matrix 1.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 - I updated the code again.

Comment: Hi! Almost! It works fine, except when deleting rows from matrix 1. It crashes with message "Warning: Error in cbind: number of rows of matrices must match (see arg 2)..." You can delete rows and columns from matrix 2 without problem, and they are correctly reactively reflected in matrix 1. I can insert rows into matrix 1 without problem and they are correctly reactively reflected in matrix 2. I'll revise my post with a some lines of code I used in another draft to conform dimensions of <> matrices, though I prefer your cbind() and rbind() solutions, they are far cleaner.

Comment: I seem to have fixed the issue by simply adding if(nrow(tmpMat2) > nrow(tmpMat1)){
tmpMat1 <- rbind(tmpMat1, rep(NA, ncol(tmpMat1)))}, immediately beneath your lines of code for if(nrow(tmpMat1) > nrow(tmpMat2)){...}. I'm trying to break it by running all sorts of weird scenarios, so far so good!

Comment: One other question. When running this code, NA's fill in any dimension gaps which is how it's supposed to work. In the R Studio console I get the message "Warning in coerce(unlist(row)) : NAs introduced by coercion" as the matrix reshapes. Can this message be suppressed? In this case introducing NAs by coercion is good and intended